Blazor Server Authentication without using Identity using HttpContext.SignInAsync
Been trying to get Authentication working for a Blazor Server Side app with my own Identity check (I do not want to use SqlServer or that mechanism). All seems fine accept that HttpContext is always null. I have seen many, many suggestions on how to overcome this but none work:
Blazor server Application Authentication without Identity Server
Everything else seems to work except I cannot sign in the identity I am creating (and logout also). I have tried removing the interactive rendering, but to no avail.
Here is the Login.razor code:
@page "/login"
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))
@inject LoginApiClient LoginApi
@inject UserApiClient UserApi
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager 
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
@using MayApp.Web.APIClients;
@using MayApp.Web.Models
@using Blazorise.Components
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

<PageTitle>Login - My App</PageTitle>
<h1>Login</h1>

<div>
<Validations @ref="@ValidationsRef" Model="@login" ValidateOnLoad="false">
    <Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is4">
        <FieldLabel RequiredIndicator>User Name</FieldLabel>
        <Validation Validator="ValidationRule.IsNotEmpty">
            <TextEdit @bind-Text="@login.UserName" MaxLength="30">
                <Feedback>
                    <ValidationError>Please provide an User Name</ValidationError>
                </Feedback>
            </TextEdit>
        </Validation>
    </Field>
    @if (@error)
    {
        <Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is4" > 
           <Text TextColor="TextColor.Danger">@errorMessage</Text>
        </Field>
    }
    <Field ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is4">
        <FieldLabel RequiredIndicator>Password</FieldLabel>
        <Validation Validator="@ValidatePassword">
            <TextEdit @bind-Text="@login.Password" Placeholder="Enter a Password" MaxLength="50" Role="TextRole.Password">
                <Feedback>
                    <ValidationError>Invalid password. Passwords must be between 8 and 30 characters long, one number, one lower and one upper case letter, and one special character.</ValidationError>
                </Feedback>
            </TextEdit>
        </Validation>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Button Color="Color.Success" Clicked="@Authenticate">Login</Button>
    </Field>

</Validations>
</div>



@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext httpcontext { get; set; } = default!;

    private MyApp.Web.Models.Login login = new();
    const string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,30}$";
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    bool error = false;

    Validations ValidationsRef { get; set; }

    void ValidatePassword(ValidatorEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(e.Value), passwordPattern);
        e.Status = isMatch ? ValidationStatus.Success : ValidationStatus.Error;
    }

    async void Authenticate()
    {
        var result = await MyApp.Login(login);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            if (result.PasswordResetNeeded)
            {
                // Provide a link to reset password.
                error = true;
                errorMessage = result.Message;
                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            } 
            else if (result.Users != null && result.Users.Count > 0)
            {
                User user = result.Users[0];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Role))
                {
                    errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    error = false;
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
                    };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    await httpcontext.SignInAsync(principal);
                    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/"); // Should be home

                }
                else
                {
                    error = true;
                    errorMessage = "Invalid UserName or Password.";
                    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
                errorMessage = "Invalid UserName or Password.";
                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error = true;
            errorMessage = "Invalid UserName or Password.";
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

}

The failure is always with the Context being null at this line:
   await httpcontext.SignInAsync(principal);

My program.cs looks like this:
using Blazored.Toast;
using Blazorise;
using Blazorise.Bootstrap5;
using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome;
using CollectXScore.Web.APIClients;
using CollectXScore.Web.Components;
using CollectXScore.Web.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

// This is a Blazor Server Application (NOT a Webassembly App)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add service defaults & Aspire components.
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddOutputCache();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
// Authentication and Authorization services
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
    AddCookie(options => 
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessdenied";
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services
    .AddBlazorise(options =>
    {
        options.Immediate = true;
    })
    .AddBootstrap5Providers()
    .AddFontAwesomeIcons();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
    ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseOutputCache();
app.MapDefaultEndpoints();
app.Run();

Is there a way to store off the HttpContext at startup and then reference it or elsewhere in the code? Or some of mechanism not documented?

Firstly, @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)) is actually InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender:false)). This doesn't remove interactive, but remove the prerender (SSR). If you want to disable interactive render only use prerender(SSR), just delete the @rendermode in Page and App.razor. "no mode" means SSR. Disable prerender
HttpContext is null in interactive rendermode. Only avaliable in SSR. Access HttpContext in blazor
If your project is using SSR all over the project, you could use HttpContext.SigninAsync like MVC . But [Authorize] won't work in interactive mode.
When rendermode is InteractiveServer(prerender:false), the project using websocket instead of Http. So HttpContext is not available. Blazor acturally has another authentication system which get user identity from AuthenticationStateProvider instead of HttpContext. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/authentication-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server

Thanks! The AuthenticationStateProvider was the only mechanism I could get to work. Has one issue - if I refresh the page it seems to lose the authentication. Researching that now.
